# Windows Group Policy Management - Session host limit group policy doesn't work as expected

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I have created a group policy to end the sessions which are disconnected automatically & the settings of RDP session timeouts are located in the following GPO section Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host -> Session Time Limits

This is properly applied & I can see it from RSOP as well as from GPresults. But the sessions are not ending as expected.

Any thoughts ? Is this only working if we have configured Remote Desktop Session Host role on the server ?

Answer (score 1):

The sessions were created before the policy was applied. Session limits are applied at logon, using the limits applied at the time of logon.